Forcing gcc to use /usr/gnu/bin/ld or /usr/gld rather than /usr/ld on Solaris 11.3 (Sparc)
I am trying to build libffi-3.4.5.  The README file states that I must use GNU as and ld.  On Solaris 11.3, these are either /usr/gas (or /usr/gnu/bin/as) and /usr/gld (or /usr/gnu/bin/ld).  Short of recompiling gcc to use the GNU versions, how do I ask gcc to use them?
I tried AS=/usr/gnu/bin/as and LD=/usr/gnu/bin/ld.  Both are ignored.
I tried gcc-14.1.0 and gcc-4.8.2 on Solaris 11.3/sparc.  My PATH is /usr/gnu/bin:/home/build/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin

Please post more details such as your OS version, gcc version, value of the PATH envval.

That's what the -B option is for, or the GCC_EXEC_PREFIX environment variable

@o11c  Thank you -- that worked (by adding -B/usr/gnu/bin).  Will you make this an answer or do I withdraw the question?
